# RowFilter for Bigtable - need only column qualifiers and NOT cell values

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to make use of the google-cloud-bigtable library. My intention is to query bigtable wherein the response should only return me the column names/qualifiers, BUT no values.

I've tried different methods like cells_per_row_limit_filter and block_all_filter, but they don't seem to do the job I want.

I don't want the 'rows' to get filtered; I just don't want to have the cell values in my results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the strip_value_transformer:
https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/bigtable/v2/data.proto#L422

Comment: Yup. That's the right answer. Figured that one out a few hours back. Thank you!!